# How to get error using if else method in rust?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I know the idiomatic way to handle errors in rust is using match statement but I am looking for other ways to do the same.

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    if let Ok(f) = fs::read_dir("/dummy"){
        println!("First: {:?}", f);
    }else{
        println!("Error");
    }
    
}
```

This works but I need the original `Result` error from `fs::read_dir("/dummy")` to be printed in the else statement. How can I do it?

Comment: Why? There are ways you can do it but they're going to be uglier and more verbose than just using `match`. E.g. more `if let`s like this `let f = fs::read_dir(..); if let Ok(good) = f {}; if let Err(e) = f {}`) or a functional style like `fs::read_dir(...).and_then(|f| println!(...) ).or_else(|e| println!(...))` .

Comment: The whole point of the `if let` construct is to be simpler than `match` when you don't need the details for the other branches. If you need those details, you will have to use `match`.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, I'd consider such an approach a bad idea, but you do have a few options, the most obvious two being "multiple `if let`s" and a "functional style" approach. I've included the match version for comparison. The code is available on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=34dc702429204819e1b0c0d55a722b26).

```
fn multiple_if_lets() {
    let f = std::fs::read_dir("/dummy");
    if let Ok(f) = &f {
        println!("First: {:?}", f);
    }
    if let Err(f) = &f {
        println!("Error: {:?}", f);
    }
}

fn functional_style() {
    std::fs::read_dir("/dummy")
        .map(|f| println!("First: {:?}", f))
        .unwrap_or_else(|f| println!("Error: {:?}", f));
}

fn match_style() {
    match std::fs::read_dir("/dummy") {
        Ok(f) => println!("First: {:?}", f),
        Err(f) => println!("Error: {:?}", f),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Rust 1.65.0 (Nov. 2022), as mentioned by [Mara Bos](https://twitter.com/m_ou_se/status/1588190804782116864), you can do:

```rust
let Ok(f) = fs::read_dir("/dummy") else{ println!("Error"); return };
println!("First: {:?}", f);
```

> ### `let-else` statements.
>
> You can now write things like:
>
> ```
> let Ok(a) = i32::from_str("123") else { return };
> ```
>
> without needing an `if` or `match` statement.
> This can be useful to avoid deeply nested if statements.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why you don't want to use `match` because it is like a better `if let`! But you might find it useful to use an external crate like `anyhow`. You can very easily propagate all errors as one type and also add context where it makes sense.

In your `Cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies]
anyhow = "1"
```

In your code

```
use std::fs;
use anyhow::Context;

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let dir = fs::read_dir("/dummy").context("failed to read dir")?;

    // another fallible function which can return a `Result` with a 
    // different error type.
    do_something(dir).context("failed to do something")?;

    Ok(())
}
```

If `read_dir` had to fail here your program would exit and it would output the following

```
Error: failed to read dir

Caused by:
    No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

If you wanted to throw away the error but still print it out you could still use `match`.

```
let dir = match fs::read_dir("/dummy").context("failed to read dir") {
    Ok(dir) => Some(dir),
    Err(err) => {
        eprintln!("Error: {:?}", err);
        None
    }
};
```

This would output something like the following but still continue:

```
Error: failed to read dir

Caused by:
    No such file or directory (os error 2)
```